# In calendar application How to avoid duplication of synchronized account name while listing them in spinner

Tags: java, android, calendar

In building Calendar application  i have a spinner to display the list of synchronized accounts. The Code is given below... I get the list of synchronized accounts. But repitition of "Contacts' birthdays and events" and "Indian Holidays " are coming twice as below screenshot. 
MY CODE IS:

```
    final ContentResolver cr = ctx.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor ;
    if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 9 )
    {
        cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars"), new String[]{ "_id", "name" }, null, null, "_id");
    }
    else
        cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars"), new String[]{ "_id", "name" }, null, null, "_id");
    if ( cursor.moveToFirst()) 
    {
        calNames = new String[cursor.getCount()];
        final int[] calIds = new int[cursor.getCount()];
        for (int i = 0; i < (calNames.length); i++)
        {
            calIds[i] = cursor.getInt(0);
            calNames[i] = cursor.getString(1);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

    }
```

MY SCREENSOT:
[image]

Any Help is Really appreciated and Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [Set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) which wont allow duplicate types.